# List view content-deleting query crashes the application

Tags: android, sqlite, android-database

This is a code for an account book app, where total of expenses would be shown on top, and the date would be shown right below it. There's one query that tries to delete an entry and subtract the sum of the expenses to the subtracted sum upon long press of the content. App image shown here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjSgt.jpg

This, however, would crash the app, and I don't know why as I am very new on doing SQLite for android dev. Here are the code :

Main activity code, where the error is suspected to happen :

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_delete)
                .setTitle("Confirm Deletion")
                .setMessage("Are you sure to delete this content?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        EditText eContext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_context);
                        EditText ePrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_price);
                        String contexts = eContext.getText().toString();
                        int price = Integer.parseInt(ePrice.getText().toString());
                        String today_Date = getToday_date();
                        Log.d(TAG, "Value confirmed" + contexts + ", " + price + ", " + today_Date);

                        //Deletion query
                        String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + KEY_CONTEXT + "=? AND "
                                + KEY_PRICE + "=? AND " + KEY_DATE + "=?";
                        db.execSQL(query, new String[]{contexts, ePrice.getText().toString(), String.format("%s", View_DATE)});

                        // Calculate sum value
                        String queryPriceSum = String.format(
                                " SELECT SUM(price) FROM %s WHERE date = '%s'", TABLE_NAME, View_DATE);
                        cursor = db.rawQuery(queryPriceSum, null);
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                        String sum = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(0));
                        Log.d(TAG, "sum : " + sum);
                        sum_view.setText(sum);


                        // cursor.requery();
                        String querySelectAll = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE date = '%s'", TABLE_NAME, View_DATE);
                        cursor = db.rawQuery(querySelectAll, null);
                        myAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);
                        //myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        eContext.setText("");
                        ePrice.setText(0);

                        //InputMethodManager imm =
                        //        (InputMethodManager) getSystemService( Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE );
                        //imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow( ePrice.getWindowToken(), 0 );

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

DBHelper class :

```
public MyDBHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, "My_Account_Data.db", null, 4);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s ("
                + "%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + "%s TEXT, "
                + "%s INTEGER, "
                + "%s TEXT);", TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID, KEY_CONTEXT, KEY_PRICE, KEY_DATE);
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String query = String.format("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s", TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL(query);
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

Cursor Adapter class :

```
 String TAG = "MyCursorAdapter";
    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
        View v = inflater.inflate( R.layout.list_item, parent,false );
        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        TextView item_context = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.item_context );
        TextView item_price = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.item_price );


        String contexts = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( MainActivity.KEY_CONTEXT ) );
        String price = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( MainActivity.KEY_PRICE ) );

        Log.d(TAG, contexts + ", " + price);

        item_context.setText( contexts );
        item_price.setText( price );

    }
```

Logcat :

```
2019-06-21 08:32:57.052 17280-17280/org.androidtown.mycalendar D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2019-06-21 08:32:57.188 17280-17280/org.androidtown.mycalendar D/ViewRootImpl@ef6be96[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
2019-06-21 08:32:57.190 17280-17280/org.androidtown.mycalendar D/AbsListView: onTouchUp() mTouchMode : -1
2019-06-21 08:32:57.650 17280-17280/org.androidtown.mycalendar D/ViewRootImpl@1632a00[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
2019-06-21 08:32:57.751 17280-17280/org.androidtown.mycalendar D/ViewRootImpl@1632a00[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
2019-06-21 08:32:57.768 17280-17280/org.androidtown.mycalendar D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-06-21 08:32:57.770 17280-17280/org.androidtown.mycalendar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.androidtown.mycalendar, PID: 17280
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:627)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
        at org.androidtown.mycalendar.MainActivity$2$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:128)
        at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
2019-06-21 08:32:57.790 17280-17280/org.androidtown.mycalendar I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17280 SIG: 9
```

Any help for pinpointing the problem and/or on solving it would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Please attach crash logs, the link provided is having the entire logs.

Comment: Thank you for the correction -- it's edited now to only show the crash logs...

Comment: It's crashing in your `MainActivity`, somewhere you are using `Integer.parseInt` but the string passed in null. If it's still unclear, please attach MainActivity's code.

Comment: I've attached the problematic code, I hope it can be detected sooner or later...

Answer (score 0):

Seems `ePrice.getText().toString()` is null, have you set any text in `ePrices`?
Feel free to ask any further on this.

Comment: Thank you, and I don't think so. The string was indeed null at the start, I just don't know how to refine the code so that the deletion query becomes doable by the app.

Comment: Is your previous crash resolved now? "I just don't know how to refine the code so that the deletion query becomes doable by the app." is this something new?